torch.cuda.is_available() returns 'False'
I am working on Azure Machine Learning Studio Jupyter Notebook, I have created a conda virtual environment with python 3.8.19. My compute instance has NVIDIA Tesla T4 GPU. I have installed Pytorch with conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=12.1 -c pytorch -c nvidia. But when I print torch.cuda.is_available() it returns False.
nvidia-smi returns
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.154.05             Driver Version: 535.154.05   CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla T4                       Off | 00000001:00:00.0 Off |                  Off |
| N/A   38C    P0              26W /  70W |      2MiB / 16384MiB |      6%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

nvcc --version returns:
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:07:16_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243

conda list returns:
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                 conda_forge    conda-forge
_openmp_mutex             4.5                       2_gnu    conda-forge
aiohttp                   3.9.5                    pypi_0    pypi
aiohttp-cors              0.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
aiosignal                 1.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
annotated-types           0.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
anyio                     4.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
asttokens                 2.4.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
async-timeout             4.0.3                    pypi_0    pypi
attrs                     23.2.0                   pypi_0    pypi
backcall                  0.2.0              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
blas                      1.0                         mkl  
bottleneck                1.3.8            py38h7f0c24c_0    conda-forge
brotli-python             1.1.0            py38h17151c0_1    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.8                hd590300_5    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2024.2.2             hbcca054_0    conda-forge
cachetools                5.3.3                    pypi_0    pypi
certifi                   2024.2.2           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
charset-normalizer        3.3.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
click                     8.1.7                    pypi_0    pypi
colorama                  0.4.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
colorful                  0.5.6                    pypi_0    pypi
comm                      0.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
cuda-cudart               12.1.105                      0    nvidia
cuda-cupti                12.1.105                      0    nvidia
cuda-libraries            12.1.0                        0    nvidia
cuda-nvrtc                12.1.105                      0    nvidia
cuda-nvtx                 12.1.105                      0    nvidia
cuda-opencl               12.4.127                      0    nvidia
cuda-runtime              12.1.0                        0    nvidia
debugpy                   1.8.1            py38h17151c0_0    conda-forge
decorator                 5.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
distlib                   0.3.8                    pypi_0    pypi
dnspython                 2.6.1                    pypi_0    pypi
email-validator           2.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
exceptiongroup            1.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
executing                 2.0.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
fastapi                   0.111.0                  pypi_0    pypi
fastapi-cli               0.0.3                    pypi_0    pypi
ffmpeg                    4.3                  hf484d3e_0    pytorch
filelock                  3.14.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
freetype                  2.12.1               h267a509_2    conda-forge
frozenlist                1.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
fsspec                    2024.5.0           pyhff2d567_0    conda-forge
gmp                       6.3.0                h59595ed_1    conda-forge
gmpy2                     2.1.5            py38h6a1700d_1    conda-forge
gnutls                    3.6.15               he1e5248_0  
google-api-core           2.19.0                   pypi_0    pypi
google-auth               2.29.0                   pypi_0    pypi
googleapis-common-protos  1.63.0                   pypi_0    pypi
grpcio                    1.63.0                   pypi_0    pypi
h11                       0.14.0                   pypi_0    pypi
httpcore                  1.0.5                    pypi_0    pypi
httptools                 0.6.1                    pypi_0    pypi
httpx                     0.27.0                   pypi_0    pypi
huggingface_hub           0.23.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
idna                      3.7                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
importlib-metadata        7.1.0              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
importlib-resources       6.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
importlib_metadata        7.1.0                hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
intel-openmp              2023.1.0         hdb19cb5_46306  
ipykernel                 6.29.3             pyhd33586a_0    conda-forge
ipython                   8.12.0             pyh41d4057_0    conda-forge
ipywidgets                8.1.2              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
jedi                      0.19.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jinja2                    3.1.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
joblib                    1.4.0            py38h06a4308_0  
jsonschema                4.22.0                   pypi_0    pypi
jsonschema-specifications 2023.12.1                pypi_0    pypi
jupyter_client            8.6.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              5.7.2            py38h578d9bd_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_widgets        3.0.10             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
keyutils                  1.6.1                h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
krb5                      1.21.2               h659d440_0    conda-forge
lame                      3.100             h166bdaf_1003    conda-forge
lcms2                     2.16                 hb7c19ff_0    conda-forge
ld_impl_linux-64          2.40                 h55db66e_0    conda-forge
lerc                      4.0.0                h27087fc_0    conda-forge
libcublas                 12.1.0.26                     0    nvidia
libcufft                  11.0.2.4                      0    nvidia
libcufile                 1.9.1.3                       0    nvidia
libcurand                 10.3.5.147                    0    nvidia
libcusolver               11.4.4.55                     0    nvidia
libcusparse               12.0.2.55                     0    nvidia
libdeflate                1.20                 hd590300_0    conda-forge
libedit                   3.1.20191231         he28a2e2_2    conda-forge
libffi                    3.4.2                h7f98852_5    conda-forge
libgcc-ng                 13.2.0               h77fa898_7    conda-forge
libgfortran-ng            11.2.0               h00389a5_1  
libgfortran5              11.2.0               h1234567_1  
libgomp                   13.2.0               h77fa898_7    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.17                 hd590300_2    conda-forge
libidn2                   2.3.4                h5eee18b_0  
libjpeg-turbo             3.0.0                hd590300_1    conda-forge
libnpp                    12.0.2.50                     0    nvidia
libnsl                    2.0.1                hd590300_0    conda-forge
libnvjitlink              12.1.105                      0    nvidia
libnvjpeg                 12.1.1.14                     0    nvidia
libpng                    1.6.43               h2797004_0    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.18               h36c2ea0_1    conda-forge
libsqlite                 3.45.3               h2797004_0    conda-forge
libstdcxx-ng              13.2.0               hc0a3c3a_7    conda-forge
libtasn1                  4.19.0               h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.6.0                h1dd3fc0_3    conda-forge
libunistring              0.9.10               h7f98852_0    conda-forge
libuuid                   2.38.1               h0b41bf4_0    conda-forge
libwebp-base              1.4.0                hd590300_0    conda-forge
libxcb                    1.15                 h0b41bf4_0    conda-forge
libxcrypt                 4.4.36               hd590300_1    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.2.13               hd590300_5    conda-forge
lightning-utilities       0.11.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
llvm-openmp               8.0.1                hc9558a2_0    conda-forge
markdown-it-py            3.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
markupsafe                2.1.5            py38h01eb140_0    conda-forge
matplotlib-inline         0.1.7              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
mdurl                     0.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
mkl                       2023.1.0         h213fc3f_46344  
mkl-service               2.4.0            py38h5eee18b_1  
mkl_fft                   1.3.8            py38h5eee18b_0  
mkl_random                1.2.4            py38hdb19cb5_0  
mpc                       1.3.1                hfe3b2da_0    conda-forge
mpfr                      4.2.1                h9458935_1    conda-forge
mpmath                    1.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
msgpack                   1.0.8                    pypi_0    pypi
multidict                 6.0.5                    pypi_0    pypi
ncurses                   6.5                  h59595ed_0    conda-forge
nest-asyncio              1.6.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nettle                    3.7.3                hbbd107a_1  
networkx                  2.8.8              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
numexpr                   2.8.4            py38hc78ab66_1  
numpy                     1.24.3           py38hf6e8229_1  
numpy-base                1.24.3           py38h060ed82_1  
opencensus                0.11.4                   pypi_0    pypi
opencensus-context        0.1.3                    pypi_0    pypi
openh264                  2.1.1                h4ff587b_0  
openjpeg                  2.5.2                h488ebb8_0    conda-forge
openssl                   3.3.0                hd590300_0    conda-forge
orjson                    3.10.3                   pypi_0    pypi
packaging                 24.0               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pandas                    2.0.3            py38h1128e8f_0  
parso                     0.8.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pexpect                   4.9.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5                   py_1003    conda-forge
pillow                    10.3.0           py38h9e66945_0    conda-forge
pip                       24.0               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pkgutil-resolve-name      1.3.10                   pypi_0    pypi
platformdirs              4.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pooch                     1.7.0            py38h06a4308_0  
prometheus-client         0.20.0                   pypi_0    pypi
prompt-toolkit            3.0.42             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
prompt_toolkit            3.0.42               hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
proto-plus                1.23.0                   pypi_0    pypi
protobuf                  4.25.3                   pypi_0    pypi
psutil                    5.9.8            py38h01eb140_0    conda-forge
pthread-stubs             0.4               h36c2ea0_1001    conda-forge
ptyprocess                0.7.0              pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
pure_eval                 0.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
py-spy                    0.3.14                   pypi_0    pypi
pyarrow                   16.1.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pyasn1                    0.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pyasn1-modules            0.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pydantic                  2.7.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pydantic-core             2.18.2                   pypi_0    pypi
pygments                  2.18.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pysocks                   1.7.1              pyha2e5f31_6    conda-forge
python                    3.8.19          hd12c33a_0_cpython    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.9.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python-dotenv             1.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
python-multipart          0.0.9                    pypi_0    pypi
python-tzdata             2024.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python_abi                3.8                      4_cp38    conda-forge
pytorch                   2.3.0               py3.8_cpu_0    pytorch
pytorch-cuda              12.1                 ha16c6d3_5    pytorch
pytorch-lightning         2.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pytorch-mutex             1.0                         cpu    pytorch
pytz                      2024.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyyaml                    6.0.1            py38h01eb140_1    conda-forge
pyzmq                     26.0.3           py38ha44f8e3_0    conda-forge
ray                       2.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
readline                  8.2                  h8228510_1    conda-forge
referencing               0.35.1                   pypi_0    pypi
regex                     2024.5.15        py38hfb59056_0    conda-forge
requests                  2.31.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
rich                      13.7.1                   pypi_0    pypi
rpds-py                   0.18.1                   pypi_0    pypi
rsa                       4.9                      pypi_0    pypi
safetensors               0.4.3            py38h0cc4f7c_0    conda-forge
scikit-learn              1.3.0            py38h1128e8f_1  
scipy                     1.10.1           py38hf6e8229_1  
setuptools                69.5.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
shellingham               1.5.4                    pypi_0    pypi
six                       1.16.0             pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
smart-open                7.0.4                    pypi_0    pypi
sniffio                   1.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
sqlite                    3.45.3               h2c6b66d_0    conda-forge
stack_data                0.6.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
starlette                 0.37.2                   pypi_0    pypi
sympy                     1.12            pypyh9d50eac_103    conda-forge
tbb                       2021.8.0             hdb19cb5_0  
tensorboardx              2.6.2.2                  pypi_0    pypi
threadpoolctl             2.2.0              pyh0d69192_0  
tk                        8.6.13          noxft_h4845f30_101    conda-forge
tokenizers                0.15.1           py38h22610ee_0  
torchaudio                2.3.0                  py38_cpu    pytorch
torchmetrics              1.4.0.post0        pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
torchvision               0.18.0                 py38_cpu    pytorch
tornado                   6.4              py38h01eb140_0    conda-forge
tqdm                      4.66.4             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
traitlets                 5.14.3             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
transformers              4.37.2           py38h06a4308_0  
typer                     0.12.3                   pypi_0    pypi
typing-extensions         4.11.0               hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing_extensions         4.11.0             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
ujson                     5.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
urllib3                   2.2.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
uvicorn                   0.29.0                   pypi_0    pypi
uvloop                    0.19.0                   pypi_0    pypi
virtualenv                20.26.2                  pypi_0    pypi
watchfiles                0.21.0                   pypi_0    pypi
wcwidth                   0.2.13             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
websockets                12.0                     pypi_0    pypi
wheel                     0.43.0             pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
widgetsnbextension        4.0.10             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
wrapt                     1.16.0                   pypi_0    pypi
xorg-libxau               1.0.11               hd590300_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxdmcp             1.1.3                h7f98852_0    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.6                h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
yaml                      0.2.5                h7f98852_2    conda-forge
yarl                      1.9.4                    pypi_0    pypi
zeromq                    4.3.5                h75354e8_4    conda-forge
zipp                      3.17.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.13               hd590300_5    conda-forge
zstd                      1.5.6                ha6fb4c9_0    conda-forge

How will I be able to activate GPU torch? Please help.
I tried to install Torch with GPU support with following command: conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=12.1 -c pytorch -c nvidia but did not work.
